# Can I not use ARC if app has to be comptible with mac os x 10.5 onwards?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deploy to Snow Leopard with ARC enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696201/how-to-deploy-to-snow-leopard-with-arc-enabled)

Quoting from Hillegas Book on Cocoa Programming for Max OS X from the memory management chapter

The new solution, introduced in Mac OS 10.7 and iOS 5, is automatic reference counting, more commonly known as ARC. ARC relies on the original retain-count mechanism but with a twist: The compiler manages the bookkeeping of retain counts for you.

I am writing a Max OS X application that has to be compatible with 10.5 and onwards till 10.8. So my understadnig based on the above is that if ARC was introduced in 10.7 does it mean that if I build my application on a platform 10.7 with ARC, the app won't be able to run on 10.5 and 10.6 ? because ARC feature was introduced in 10.7

What memory management should I use if the app has to be compatible with 10.5/6/7/8

Also it might be important to tell, my backend is mostly in C++ (and I know I have to manage C++ memory myself and not relying on ARC) and front end in Objective-C

My development platform is 10.7 Lion / Xcode 4.3

Senior please shed some light.

**Edit**
From the comments I understand that ARC is depndent on runtime support as well, which essentially means  it is not suitable in my case. Also it is not supported on 10.5 anyways, so should I do manual memory management ?

Comment: Closely related, likely answers your question: [ARC on older versions of iOS and OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14208427)

Comment: OK so if ARC needs runtime as well, what is the suggestion, manual memory management ?

Comment: @Ahmed: I would use MMR. You *could* use GC but it is officially deprecated on OS X 10.8, so if you want to target 10.5 to 10.8 your best bet is to use MMR.

Comment: Even though I have my answer, I am surprised why it is considered duplicate, my minimum deployment platform is 10.5 'Leopard' not 'snow Leopard' as per answers on this page ARC not at all supported on 'Leapord' . How is this a duplicate Question ??? ! that question is about 'Snow Leapord which does support some kind of ARC'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would choose MRR.

No portion of ARC is available on OS X versions prior to 10.6. Zeroing weak references requires 10.7.

See the Apple ARC availability matrix [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/).

> The Snow Leopard version of Xcode 4.2 doesn’t support ARC at all on OS
>   X, because it doesn’t include the 10.7 SDK. Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard
>   does support ARC for iOS though, and Xcode 4.2 for Lion supports both
>   OS X and iOS. This means you need a Lion system to build an ARC
>   application that runs on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

ARC is a SDK feature and most features are available on older OSes as long as you compile using the 10.7+ SDK.

Related: [How to deploy to Snow Leopard with ARC enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696201/how-to-deploy-to-snow-leopard-with-arc-enabled)

> While it's possible to build programs using ARC that run on Mac OS X 10.6 and iOS 4, zeroing weak references are not available on those OSes. All weak references must be __unsafe_unretained here. Because non-zeroing weak references are so dangerous, this limitation significantly decreases the attractiveness of ARC on those OSes in my view.

Oh, and only on 10.6 and later. Leopard isn't supported.

Comment: So given my application deployment needs, is the suggestion , manual memory management ?

Comment: ARC is not just an SDK feature, there is a library (ARCLite) that is required. iOS 5.0 and Mac OS X 10.7 (and later versions) include these functions.

Comment: I would use MMR, GC is officially deprecated but MMR is always an option.

Comment: For OS X prior to 10.7 I also would also use MMR.